# Динамическая загрузка контента между переходом по пунктам меню

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, websocket

У меня есть приложение, в котором пользователь взаимодействует со страницами. Есть меню, в котором можно кликнуть на пункт и попасть на страницу. Проблема в том, что при переходе на другую страницу нужна перезагрузка, а хочется сделать так, чтобы перезагрузки не было, например, как в VK при переходе в музыку, новости и прочее. Я нагуглил, что делается это с помощью WebSockets, Ajax устарел. Использую я Django, понимаю в нём мало, насколько я понял, реализовывать это нужно через Django Channels, установить с юзером соединение по websocket и непрерывно передавать данные. Все туториалы, которые я нашёл мне непонятные, обычно они касаются чатов в реальном времени, мне нужен лишь переход по ссылке.

Кто-то может мне объяснить как это делается или скинуть мне уроки по динамической загрузке, можно статьи

Comment: Ну так и вк написан не на django. Они используют свою версию php https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPHP
А приложения на ios android думаю писались на swift/java мб c#/cpp

Comment: посмотрите статью - https://www.insight-it.ru/highload/2012/arkhitektura-instagram/ может быть она вам чем-то поможет, подскажет что вам гуглить -_-

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato я уже нагуглил, как это делается - через каналы джанго. Другой вопрос в том, как это реализуется через эти каналы, туториалы, которые я нашел относятся к чату, а динамический переход по страницам я не нашел, поэтому и объявил конкурс за туториал нормальный, хочу понять как